# how to simulate a keypress on document load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Have a Div and I would like to use a jquery function to automatically focus to it being it it the only part of the page with a scrollbar. I researched a way to do this and came up with nothing and I also researched a way to simulate a keypress (tab) on document load and found nothing again. Could somebody help me find the solution to me question one way or the other??

Comment: Is `$.scrollTo()` what you're looking for?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: did your research include a simple google? https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=simulate%20keypress%20event%20jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() { // when document loaded
  $( "#yourdiv" ).focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Focus on something after body load using this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "youritem" ).focus();
});
```

see: [jquery focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus) for reference.

Comment: use # if it is id or . if class.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cls").on("focus",function(){
        alert("Focus is on Div");   
    });
    $(".cls").focus();
});
</script>
```